# Computer name description

Tags: windows, active-directory

we are in the process of migrating windows operating systems and to make future search easier in AD I'd like to put in more details into the description box in the computer name dialog.

e.g.

Blade03|BL465c|WIN2008R2|4GB|2CPU|75GB|10.67.41.53

I searched this on my AD and nothing comes up, is there an easier way to do this, so the description becomes searchable.

Comment: How about using the existing attribute fields like `operatingSystem` or use extensionAttributes for things like HW config or static IP addresses? A pipe-separated list in the description field sounds like a horrible idea

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen `extensionAttributeN` properties are added by Exchange, so unless you have/had it your AD will not have your AD will not have these properties. `employeeNumber` is a property in the base schema that's not used, so it's generally an option, especially for computer accounts. They are well abused for the purpose suggested, so be careful of other software doing the same. We have startup and logon scripts that update various information in the extensionAttribure too. Works great except users aren't allowed to update their own by default (a quick permissions change fixes that).

Comment: @ChrisS Correct, but you could introduce new attributes in the Schema specific to your use case, doesn't *have* to be the `extensionAttributeN`'s.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That's actually Microsoft's recommended method. Issue is, once you've added to the schema you can't ever remove it. So most people choose not to make irreversible changes to AD.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer, let me know if that's the problem you're running into, and update your question accordingly. (Problem being that the local computer description is not the same as the AD description attribute).  Your question isn't especially clear and it's already leading to some confusion as to what the actual problem is.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the description stored in the "computer name dialogue box" (System Properties dialogue) is different than the computer object's description attribute in Active Directory.

Typically, you'd use Active Directory Users and Computer (ADUC) or a script to update the description attribute in Active Directory, and not worry about setting the description on the local machine, because as you observed, the local machine description isn't searchable in AD, and therefore of limited utility.

System Properties description field:

[image]

Active Directory description attribute:

[image]

(I guess you'll just have to take my word that these are for the same machine.)

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest way to search AD is with PowerShell. If you're on a client OS, install RSAT (it's different for each OS or I'd link you). Make sure the feature is enabled: Remote Server Administration Tools -> Role Administration -> AD DS and AD LDS Tools -> Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell.

Then just open PowerShell and do something like

```
Get-ADComputer -filter {description -like "Blade03*"}
```